# Declaring Mat variable c++ causes program to terminate early without errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I've successfully linked all the required libraries etc. to my c++ project yet for some reason whenever i try 
    Mat image;

the program terminates without any errors. If i try

```
int main() {
    cout<<"TEST";
    Mat a;
    return 0;
}
```

it wont even show the "TEST" on the terminal but simply states 
 (exit value: -1,073,741,515) using eclipse. Im not sure what to make of it since theres no errors and the exit value shows nothing when i search google for it. Is there anything else i could try, or have i missed something?

The code is copied below, together with the c++ build settings. The 'build' folder is a folder i created myself for cmake source directory.

[Libraries included in Mingw C++ Linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQDBX.png)

[GCC C++ compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NreeP.png)

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    cv::Mat im_gray;
    return 0;


}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: cout << "TEST" doesn't have to produce any output, depending on how the program exits. you should use cerr to make sure each character is flushed.

Comment: i tried that, still nothing :/

Comment: `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"`

Comment: if you remove the Mat line, does it behave like expected?